# What is the origin of the phrase ‘orc and pie’?

Tags: terminology, dungeon-design

I'd like to know where this unique phrase came from. “Orc and pie” has become shorthand for a style of simple dungeon design, but where did it originate?

Comment: Since I’ve been gaming 30 years and have never heard the phrase, perhaps you could expand your question to indicate where you heard it and why you think it’s a widespread saying.

Comment: A first for me as well, but also a wonderful bit of RPG lore.  Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

## Presenting Monte Cook’s ["The Orc and the Pie"](http://web.archive.org/web/20010805205352/http://www.montecook.com:80/arch_lineos11.html), ©2001

> #### The World's Shortest (Yet Technically Complete) Adventure: A Parody
>
> "The Orc and the Pie"
>
> **Adventure Background:** An orc has a pie.
>
> **Adventure Synopsis:** The PCs kill the orc and take his pie.
>
> **Adventure Hook:** The PCs are hungry for pie.
>
> **Room 1: The Orc's Pie Room**
>
> > You see an orc with a pie.
>
> The room is 10 feet by 10 feet.
>
> **Creature:** An orc.
>
> **Treasure:** A pie.
>
> **Concluding the Adventure:** Pie tastes good.
>
> **Further Adventures:** Somewhere, there is a bakery making these good
> pies. Perhaps it's guarded by more orcs.

WHAT DO YOU DO???

Comment: Obviously you go off somewhere else and buy a tart.

Comment: Or sit in a bar and strike up a conversation with one. Whatever... :-)

Answer (score 53):

## It was an example adventure by Monte Cook

It seems to have been made as an example adventure that is as short as possible while still being an actual adventure hook, but it is no longer available on their website. (Here's [an entry for it on rpggeek.com](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/149795/orc-and-pie), which puts its publication at 2002, and shows [an image](https://rpggeek.com/image/2975882/orc-and-pie) for it that dates it to 2001.)

The synopsis is basically:

> There's an orc, he has a pie, the adventurers are hungry.

It has everything an adventure needs: An adversary, a MacGuffin the players need, and a reason to get it.

Somehow this caught on and more people started using "Orc & Pie" as a phrase to mean "extremely simplistic adventure." It essentially became a meme, which helped spread its name.

In fact, if [Wil Wheaton is to be believed](https://cf.geekdo-images.com/imagepagezoom/img/nogSKJcTvxFHq7pV01dfmypIPCs=/fit-in/1200x900/filters:no_upscale()/pic4036766.jpg), it can also be used as an easy starting point for learning a new game system.

Answer (score 15):

As others have already answered, “orc and pie” came from American game designer [Monte Cook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Cook)’s “The Orc and the Pie”—“The World's Shortest (Yet Technically Complete) Adventure: A Parody”.

It was posted [on Monte Cook’s website](http://www.montecook.com/arch_lineos11.html) on 2001-07-27.  The original website is no longer accessible, but it is [archived by the Internet Archive Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20010805205352/http://www.montecook.com:80/arch_lineos11.html).

Answer (score -7):

Apart from its specific history outlined in other answers, "orc and pie" was (obviously?) coined as a phonetic reference to "pork and pie" as a food of basic consistency.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack! You're facing downvotes because we expect answers to stand on their own. When you have enough reputation you'll be able to leave comments on other answers. Check out the [tour] to get yourself oriented! Happy Stacking!

Comment: The original phrase is “the orc and the pie”, which has no phonetic/syllabic resemblance to “pork and pie”, so the assertion that it was *coined* on that pattern, or even evolved toward it later, is going to need substantial citation support.

Comment: Surely it would be "pork pie" not "pork and pie"?

Comment: Keep writing good answers or asking good questions and you'll get points quickly.  Deleting downvoted answers will also remove their negative rep.

Comment: I agree completely, don't delete this